# Why can root still login remotly?

Tags: mysql5.5

I have a very strange issue I'm hoping someone may have seen before and might be kind enough to help me resolve.

On MySQL, I took away the ability for the root user to login from any remote host:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host from mysql.user where user = 'root';
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | 127.0.0.1 |
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But from my remote desktop I can still access the database as the root user...  and more strange is the fact that I don't need to enter a password to do so:

```
C:\tmp>mysql -u root -h myMysqlServer
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...

mysql> show grants;
+------------------------------+
| Grants for @%                |
+------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'%' |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

What could possibly be causing this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after changing the permissions?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same machine? I can see a different prompt in each output you posted!

Comment: Yes, I did do FLUSH PRIVILEGES, and I am connecting to the correct server.

Comment: Please use `mysql -u root -h myMysqlServer` from your remote machine again and add the output of `select user, host from mysql.user where user = 'root';`

Comment: mysql> select user, host from mysql.user where user = 'root';
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'10.1.6.9' for table 'user'

Comment: mysql_secure_installation will set a password for the MySQL root user.

Answer (score 0):

Lenniey's comment lead me to the solution:

When I display users, I see there is a user with no name and no host:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host from mysql.user;
+------------+-----------------+
| user       | host            |
+------------+-----------------+
|            |                 |  --- This user's username is blank
| root       | 127.0.0.1       |
| root       | localhost       |
...
```

So I modified the mysql.users table directly and dropped the user:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> update mysql.user set host = '%' where user = '';
MariaDB [(none)]> update mysql.user set user = 'someuser' where user = '';

MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host from mysql.user;
+------------+-----------------+
| user       | host            |
+------------+-----------------+
| someuser   | %               |
| root       | 127.0.0.1       |
| root       | localhost       |
...
```

And then I dropped the user:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> drop user someuser;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host from mysql.user;
+------------+-----------------+
| user       | host            |
+------------+-----------------+
| root       | 127.0.0.1       |
| root       | localhost       |
...
```

Problem solved.  Thanks to all who helped.